# How to specify selected element in grouped select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I specify the selected option if two of these options have the same id? I have this form input

```rb
<%= f.input :receiver_id,
                  label:        "Client",
                  collection:   receivers_keys_and_values,
                  as:           :grouped_select,
                  group_method: :last %>
```

and this method to create the select options

```rb
def receivers_keys_and_values
    [
      ["Client",  Client.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }],
      ["Program", Program.all.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }]
    ]
  end
```

The issue I have is that a client ID could be the same as a Program ID. Therefore when two ID are the same the selected one is always the Program one.
How could I specify something like?

```
selected: ["Client"][id]
or 
selected: ["Program"][id]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way ids of the selected elements will be different for programs and clients:

```rb
def receivers_keys_and_values
  [
    ["Client",  Client.all.map { |c| [c.name, "client_#{c.id}"] }],
    ["Program", Program.all.map { |p| [p.name, "program_#{p.id}"] }]
  ]
end
```

You'll also have to update form handling code in order to be able to parse input like "program_123".

You can also go fancy and refactor the code a bit:

```rb
def receivers_keys_and_values
  [Client, Program].map do |type|
    type.all.map { |entity| [entity.name, dom_id(entity) }
  end
end
```

but I'm not sure if it's clearer (should produce the same result though). Up to you.